# Changing the way autocomplete search works

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Currently I have:

```
$("#location").autocomplete({source: cities, minLength: 0, autoFocus: true});
```

The problem is that this plugin searches for matches *anywhere* inside the given inputs.

For example, if I enter "Bos" it suggests not only the words that start with "Bos", but also the words that have "bos" in the middle.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you'll have to use the callback setting for the `source` option:

> The third variation, the callback, provides the most flexibility, and
>   can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback
>   gets two arguments:
>
> - A request object, with a single property called "term", which
>     refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, when the
>     user entered "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will
>     equal "new yo".
> - A response callback, which expects a single argument to contain
>     the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on
>     the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above
>     for simple local data (String-Array or Object-Array with
>     label/value/both properties). It's important when providing a custom
>     source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always
>     call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This
>     ensures that the widget always has the correct state. ([source](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/))

**Untested:**

```
$(function() {
    var options = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Foobar"];

    $(<selector>).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
                    var matches = [],
                        term = request.term.toLowerCase(),
                        termLen = term.length;

                    for (var i = 0, j = options.length; i < j; i++) {
                         if (options[i].substring(0, termLen).toLowerCase() == term) {
                             matches.push(options[i]);
                         }
                    }

                    response(matches);
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: @krn Great. I bet you could make it prettier, but I trust you'll get the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

As @jensgram said You could use `source` method.

Something like that works for me in my web-app:

```
$("#location").autocomplete({
    source : function(request, response) {
        /* cities.html?query=... should return json array words starting with query value */
        $.getJSON('cities.html?query=' + request.term, function(data) {
            response(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy in the jQuery Autocomplete plugin, whose [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions) answers this:

> `matchContains` | `Boolean` | `Default: false`
>
> Whether or not the comparison
>   looks inside (i.e. does "ba" match "foo bar") the search results.
>   Important only if you use caching. Don't mix with autofill.

You may wish to switch to this from jQuery UI Autocomplete as it's more fully-featured.

Comment: @krn: Ah, oops. :) Perhaps switch to the jQuery autocomplete plugin, then? It's more fully-featured.

Comment: Jörn Zaefferer's jQuery AutoComplete was a wonderful plugin for autocomplete.
But its now deprecated and so, it would be very hard to maintain that for any project for the latest versions of jQuery.
Here is what Jörn Zaefferer has to say

**Note (2010-06-23): This plugin is deprecated and not developed anymore. Its successor is part of jQuery UI, and this migration guide explains how to get from this plugin to the new one. This page will remain as it is for reference, but won’t be updated anymore.**

So its better to switch to jQUery UI - AutoComplete.

Comment: @Ashish: You're right. That's a great shame, given the lack of available options in the UI version. Incidentally, the [migration guide](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide) says "The builtin matcher for local data will do a case-insensitive match-contains, everything else has to be implemented on the serverside or using the source option. The combobox linked just above also has an example for that", so there's the answer.